# inserting tinymce content to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to insert the content of a textarea that uses tinymce into a mysql database on codeigniter 3.

the view:

```
<form action="">
  <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<script>
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#content',
  plugins:  [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages preview emoticons media",
    "textcolor placeholder"
     ],
    toolbar: "bold italic underline strikethrough backcolor emoticons autoresize | bullist numlist outdent indent | insertfile | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link media image jbimages undo redo preview",
    menubar:false,
    paste_data_images: true,
    relative_urls: false,
    height : "420",
    paste_word_valid_elements: "b,strong,i,em,h1,h2,u,p,ol,ul,li,a[href],span,color,mark",
    relative_urls : false,
    media_dimensions: false,
    media_poster: false,
    content_css: "/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    setup: function (editor) {
      editor.on('change', function () {
        tinymce.triggerSave();
      });
    }
});
</script>
```

the controller:

```
$this->data['content'] = trim($this->input->post('content', TRUE));
$this->db->insert('tablename', $this->data);
```

this is the content field (in database) after inserting:

```
<p> </p>
<p>aaa</p>
<p> </p>
<p>bb</p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p>ccc</p>
```

my questions are:

1. is it OK to save html tags in the database?
2. I want to show the content after replacing all whitespaces with single space. so I tried this:

> ```
> $this->db->select('content');
> $this->db->where('id', 12);
> $content = $this->db->get()->row('content');
> $content = strip_tags($content);
> $content = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $content);
> <div><?php echo $content; ?></div>
> ```

but when I use `preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $dbfield);` it replaces the empty space with a black diamond with question mark in it. what is the correct way to achive the desired result?

Comment: you can save the tags, but you need to parameterise your queries to protect yourself.

Comment: @Takarii I thought codeigniter's Query Builder Class automatically escapes the strings?

Comment: You are absolutely right, i completely missed that in your question. My appologies